# WPF avalon wizard missing wizard control after adding System.xmal

Tags: wpf, controls, wizard

I tried Avalong Wizard control for WPF and have the following issue could you guys help me spot the problem.

1. Added Avalon reference as per the tutorial and made some changes to the xmal for the window
   and the wizrd appears. using the control or right options I can change the page, add or remove a page.
2. I added few pages and controls for each.
3. Then when I tried to rebuild the project I got the following messages

## Errors

### Error 1

The type 'System.Windows.Markup.IQueryAmbient' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. D:\SkyDrive\Dev Zone\Ms.NET\Projects\SDF_Export\SDF_Export\Window1.xaml.cs

### Error2

The type name 'IComponentConnector' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Windows.Markup'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.    D:\SkyDrive\Dev Zone\Ms.NET\Projects\SDF_Export\SDF_Export\obj\Debug\Window1.g.cs

1. Then added the reference System.Xaml - Rebuild sucessfully
2. Tested the project everything works fine in the application where I am able to switch pages

## Issue

When I come back to do more changes to the project wizard control is missing.
Now I cannot change, add, remove page using the wizrd control or the right click options.

I have attached the project here with.
[Project Files](http://www30.zippyshare.com/v/37238907/file.html)